# Float [H, !ht] does not function

Tags: floats, apa6

when I am using the place `[H]`ere command with the float package this does not function. It only works when I use the `restylefloat`, however, then my title is of course above the figure which should not be the case.

Thankful for advice!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,man,natbib,donotrepeattitle]{apa6}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,siunitx,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{minipage-marginpar}
\usepackage{float}
\floatstyle{plaintop}
\restylefloat{table}
\restylefloat{figure}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

Comment: Please post a full minimal example others can copy and test as is without having to guess parts of the document

Comment: As described in the manual of `apa6`, when the `man` option is used the `endfloat` package is loaded, the purpose of which is to move floats to the end of the document. Are you submitting this paper? Then you may have to place the figures at the end anyway (see the author instructions of the journal).

Comment: You have `\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}` twice.

Comment: your title is is not very clear, you say `[H!h]` doesn't work, but that would be a syntax error, in the text of your question you say you used `[H]` which should work if you have used the `float` package,  but your posted example code doesn't have any example of a float at all.

Comment: (@TorbjørnT.) I would have to submit the thesis in APA style, but would like to have in text figures and tables with captions below. Is there a way around "man" putting my figures to the end of the paper?

Comment: (@DavidCarlisle) by H, !ht I mean that I tried several of the float options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move `\restylefloat{figure}` before `\floatstyle{plaintop}`. That way the standard `plain` float style is used, where the caption is not forced to the top as it is with `plaintop`.

Complete minimal example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[man]{apa6}
\usepackage{float}
\restylefloat{figure}
\floatstyle{plaintop} % set floatstyle after restyling figure
\restylefloat{table}
\shorttitle{}
\begin{document}

foo

\begin{figure}[H]    
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{bar}
\end{figure}

baz
\end{document}
```